# Trying to take in characters and remove whitespace

Tags: c

Been trying to take in 10 characters and output them while ignore whitespace between characters. The if statement which is checking for either digits or alphanumeric characters is looping too many times. Any ideas?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void GetChar();

int main () {
  GetChar();

  return 0;
}

void GetChar()
{
    char input[100];
    char output [10];

    printf( "Please enter your list of ten characters: " );
    fgets(input,100,stdin);

      int outputIndex = 0;
      int f = 0;
      for (int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++ ) {

        if (isdigit(input[i]) || isalpha(input[i])) {
           input[i] = output[outputIndex];
        } 
      }

  printf( "Your array has these values: \n" );

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++ ) {
        printf( "%c", output[ i ] );
        printf("\n");
    }


}
```

Comment: Your said 10 characters, but your loop is defined to loop 100 times. I dont understand your question.

Comment: `input[i] = output[outputIndex];` should not this be `output[outputIndex++] = input[i]`? Also you need one more condition `outputIndex < 10` in for loop

Comment: What if the user enters a string shorter than 100 characters and you go beyond the end of the string in `input`? What if the user enters less than ten characters?

Comment: 1) `isdigit() || isalpha()` is the same as `isalnum()`. 2) `isalnum()` is **not** the same as `isspace()`. The character classification is tricky. Make sure you read the individual function's description *thoroughly* and make sure that code actually matches intentions.

Comment: If you just want to read in some characters and only print the ones that aren't whitespace, there is no need to buffer more than one character at a time.  Read one character.  If you want to output it, do so.  If not, do not.  The read the next character.  Trying to buffer all of the data is just complicating things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping past the end of your input string.  Don't forget in `C` strings are arrays of characters that end with a `\0` or NUL character.

Try this;

```
  for (int i = 0 ; i < strlen(input) && outputIndex<10; i++ ) {
     if (isdigit(input[i]) || isalpha(input[i])) {
      output[outputIndex++] = input[i];
    } 
  }
```

Also when you print out you should;

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < outputIndex; i++ ) {
    printf( "%c", output[ i ] );
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @kiranBiradar right good point.  It seems there are a number of issues with the code.

Comment: maybe it make sens to extend this answer and change the second loop with `output` adding `strlen(output)` to it. and after the first loop add `output[outputIndex] = '\0';`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: what if you type in more than 100 spaces? must check for i<100 as well

Comment: @div0man fgets won't accept more than 99 characters and will return a NUL terminated string so `i` will always be less than 100.

Comment: A good compiler will recognize  `strlen(input)` is constant in this code and not recompute `strlen(input)` each time.  A lesser compiler with emit `O(n*n)` code - unnecessarily inefficient. Code could change to `i < strlen(input)` to idiomatic  `input[i] != '\0'` and work well and efficient with all  compilers.

Answer (score 0):

To fix too many loops, you can modify your `for` statement to detect end of string and check for found values, too:

```
//for (int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++ ) {
for (int i = 0 ; (input[i] != '\0') && (outputIndex < 10); i++ ) {
```

You have to fix one more line to make it work as expected:

```
//input[i] = output[outputIndex];
output[outputIndex++] = input[i];
```

And we don't need to print the blank lines if less than 10 values have been typed in:

```
//for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++ ) {
for ( int i = 0 ; (output[i] != '\0') && i < 10; i++ ) {
```

Comment: `output[]` only holds ten characters, there may not be room for the NUL terminator.

Comment: that's why we also check `i < 10`, the NUL check is relevant only when there's less than 10 values in the output array

Comment: But isn't it possible that `output[outputIndex++] = input[i];` will try to write the `\0` character after the end of the output array?

Comment: how if we have the `outputIndex < 10` in place and `++` is used as postfix

Comment: I enter ten characters in places 0-9.  After the first for loop outputIndex is 10.  then you want to store a `\0` character at outputIndex.

Comment: Yes, after the first `for` the `outputIndex` is 10, but we don't use it anymore to write into `output`. The `output[outputIndex++] = input[i];` uses index of 9, assigns to output[9], and then increments it, and we exit the loop because `outputIndex < 10` returns false so it's not used anywhere with the value of 10.

Comment: My bad, I thought you were adding the NUL terminator and it would be a problem since there isn't enough room in the array.  I don't think `output[i]` will ever be equal to `\0` except for dumb luck.  It's either an uninitialized value, or a alphanumeric gotten from `input`

Comment: Oh yeah, it works only if the `output` is initialized with all 10 zeroes. Anyways, your test `i < outputIndex` makes more sense, but I'll keep mine for educational purposes. Cheers!